# Why isn't a space rendered in my <p> tag?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

[image: space not rendering]

For some reason I can't make a space appear between *to* and *Diluvio*. I'm using `React`.

```
  <div className="about-div_lastfm fade-in">
    <p className="actualmente-escuchando">Listening now to</p>
    <p className="artista">
    {" "}{songName} <span className="actualmente-escuchando">by</span>{' '}
      <a href={urlPath} target="_blank">{artistName}</a>
      <img
        className="img-nowPlaying"
        src={gif}
        alt="Ahora sonando, do do do..."
      />
    </p>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.about-div_lastfm {
  font-size: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: 100;
}
```

Comment: try `Listening now to </p>`  or  `<span className="actualmente-escuchando"> by</span>`

Comment: Probably you're using prettier. there's a config in prettier that breaks the tags `<p>`, `<span>` and `<a>` to keep the code clean, but, sometimes (like this), kinda mess everything. Didn't work putting `{" "}` between? This is the default behavior of prettier to put spaces between tags

Comment: try adding a `&nbsp;` between `<p>`. It is a non-breaking-space. `<p className="actualmente-escuchando">Listening now to</p>&nbsp;
    <p className="artista">...`

Comment: @SanishJoseph 's idea worked. Now there's visible spacing.

Comment: Great. I am just adding it as an answer. Yes I am trying to collect points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add & nbsp; between p tags as it will add a non breaking space between p tags. No space between & and nbsp; of cause. This editor is showing it as a real space that’s why I had to give a space.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```html
<div className="about-div_lastfm fade-in">
  <p className="actualmente-escuchando">
    Listening now to
    <span className="artista">{songName}</span> <span className="actualmente-escuchando">by</span>
    <a href={urlPath} target="_blank">
      {artistName}
    </a>
  </p>
  <img className="img-nowPlaying" src={gif} alt="Ahora sonando, do do do..." />
</div>
```

Comment: I copied this and pasted in my project but didn't worked.

Comment: Run the code snippet and check, is that not what you're expecting?

Comment: Yeah, but for some reason in my project it doesn't works. I'll give you an upvote for the help tho.

Comment: What is the error?